# Seo and Android WebView

Tags: seo, android

I want to know if android WebView is effective on site SEO or Not.
I have a WebView loading Google.com then i search my Keyword and find my expected result and enter it. Is it approved by google and google analytics? can this job help my Site SEO?

ps: There is no bot for doing that and they all are real people.

Comment: Why would real people search for your site if you present Google.com to them in your WebView app?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No matter why. I want to know WebView is effective or not

Comment: It matters why.  If there is a natural reason that a user might want to do this, it might be OK.   Otherwise it sounds like you are trying to trick the search engine.  Whether or not it helps could depend on whether or not it is deceptive.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller There is no trick.People search by them self and search around my site and read my contents and posts.They spend time on my website and study their lessons for paid.

Comment: Why not have webview start on your website rather than starting on Google?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Because i want to get CRL.

Comment: What is CRL?  I'm not familiar with that acronym, nor could I find something plausible for it in this context from an acronym dictionary.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I just meant Google Click